# how to replace # sign word into link tag

Tags: php, regex

How to replace `#` sign word with a **link tag** in this string.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit #amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
>       Veritatis #voluptatem quas atque sunt nemo cupiditate 
>       #tempora nisi aperiam #ipsam exercitationem!

I want to convert it into

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit [#amet](http://demo.com), 
>       consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis [#voluptatem](http://demo.com) 
>       quas atque sunt nemo cupiditate [#tempora](http://demo.com) nisi aperiam [#ipsam](http://demo.com) exercitationem!

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Please search before asking. Googling for "hashtag to link php" would've given you a lot of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to do this for a personal project:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(#(\w_+))/', '<a href="http://your/link/here/$2">$1</a>', $text);
```

`$1` is the full hashtag (ex: #hello)
`$2` is the partial tag (if you even need it) (ex: hello)

Comment: `\w` include the `_` character.